# TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, null

Mi objetivo es dar click en el botón de la página 1 y que me lleve a la página 2 con los datos cargados, este botón me lleva a la página para comprar un producto entonces se tiene que ver el título del producto escogido en la página 2.

```
//Si clicamos las botones de añadir al carrito nos da la id   
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
        const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
        console.log("Se ha clickeado el id " + id);

         //Aquí hago consultas a ajax que pregunta a php a la base de datos
        // Tenemos que pasarle la id a Funciones.php
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: './php/Funciones.php',
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                // Le pasamos la id
                data: { id: id },
                success: function (data) {
                //Nos devuelve un array
                // Parseamos los datos para que se puedan utilizar
                var datos = JSON.stringify(data);
                var cadena = JSON.parse(datos);
                //Como el contenido nos venía todo en la posición 1 del array
                //He recortado lo que quería con expresiones regulares y lo he metido
                //en **resultado** lo recorremos y al imprimir salen bien 
                for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {

                    console.log("Vuelta numero " + i + " hay " + resultado[i]);
                    //En esta parte lo que me gustaría hacer es esto:
                    //document.getElementById('titulo').innerHTML = resultado[0];
                    //pero me sale el error así que he probado lo siguiente:

                    var nombreProducto = resultado[0].toString;

                    var titulo =  document.getElementById('titulo');
                    //Nunca entra aquí
                    if (titulo) {
                        titulo.innerHTML = nombreProducto;
                        
                        window.location.href = "./PaginaProducto.html";

                    } else {
                        console.log("No va a la otra página");
                    }
           }
        });
    });
});
});
```

1. Leyendo en internet, el error hacía referencia a que era porque no
   existía esa id en el html de página 2, que en mi caso sí que existe
   porque si me pongo directamente en la página 2 (donde se tiene que
   ver el título), sí que aparece.
2. O bien porque aún no se a cargado los elementos del DOM, por lo que probé lo siguiente
   sólo, sin nada de ajax, sólo existía este código en el Javascript y sin éxito:

```js
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        var titulo =  document.getElementById('titulo');
        titulo.innerHTML = "holi";
    });
```

Aquí lo explico de forma más visual, por si tenéis dudas, estoy desesperada, he probado también con jquery con append y demás y no me da error pero tampoco me pone el texto

[image: Explicación]

Comment: No entiendo, si tienes un botón que lleva a otra página ¿Porque usas ajax?, es como querer a posta que sea más complejo. No sería mejor usar un link de toda la vida?

Comment: Hola index, a mi modesto entender, el problema que no existe el id, el js, está vinculado a un html, y es en ese que no encuentra el id, yo lo enfocaría de otra manera (seguro que alguien va a plantear algo mucho mejor), no abras una nueva página, reforma esta.

Comment: Tal vez puedas hacer que el cierre de página uno se demore hasta que cargue el js de pagina2 y pida los datos que necesita...

Comment: No puede encontrar el elemento con el ID título. ¿Por qué mejor no ubicas el elemento fuera de la función? Esta línea muevela afuera. No debería haber otro elemento con el mismo id: `var titulo =  document.getElementById('titulo');`. De paso puedes imprimir la variable antes si querés y no necesitas hacer ninguna petición para probarlo

Answer (score 0):

Es un error de concepto, al final es que es imposible que se guarde, por lo que lo tienes que guardar en una cookie como localstorage o variables de session

Comment: Hola Index, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, y lo agregues en el espacio dispuesto para tal fin (Añade un comentario) que se encuentra debajo de tu pregunta.